# Create empty initial commit though non-empty index

Tags: git

With Git < 2.40.0 it was possible to create an initial empty commit (even though files were staged) using following steps:

```bash
$ git init test
$ cd test
$ touch readme.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit" --allow-empty --only
[master (root-commit) 93f098e] initial commit
```

but with Git 2.40.0 this already commits the staged file:

```bash
$ git commit -m "initial commit" --allow-empty --only
[master (root-commit) c0b3214] initial commit
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 readme.txt
```

Is this an intentional change or a regression? If the first, how to create an empty commit though files have been staged?

Comment: Can you just avoid calling `git add`?

Comment: It's a valid question, but how often do you need to create an empty commit while having staged changes that you need this...

Comment: That sounds like a bug, given the description of the `--only` option in the manual ("If used together with `--allow-empty` paths are also not required, and an empty commit will be created."). That might be worth asking on the [git mailing list](https://git-scm.com/community).

Comment: Sounds like a bug (albeit one for a very edgy edge case)

Comment: To create an empty commit, try `GIT_INDEX_FILE=foo.index git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit" --only`. `foo.index` is a file that does not exist. And you can always use the empty tree `git commit-tree -m "initial commit" 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually that happens to me all the time. I think, although I can't quite tell since I don't have the same version of Git, that the OP is saying this misbehavior is only on the _initial_ commit, which sounds like a bug. Why should this commit be different?

Comment: @CodeCaster SmartGit does create the initial empty commit this way, because it allows easier rewriting of commits.

Comment: @ThomasS. No one use an older version than v1.8 that does not support the `--root` option, right!?!

Comment: @CodeCaster No, me too, I work from the command line.

Comment: I mention the ticket id (it’s Jira but I don’t see how it matters) in my branch names and then mention the ticket ID in either the squash commit or the merge commit that lands on the main branch. The PR description (on BitBucket) also mentions the ticket id. I’ve never had a use for empty commits in order to work with GitHub or Jira.

Comment: @Philippe: The `--root` option helps in a lot of cases, but not all. The commit command does not seem to support it.

Comment: As an alternative to an empty commit you can instead create a commit with an empty `.gitignore` file. I use a `git-initignore` script with commands `git init; touch .gitignore; git add .gitignore; git commit -m .gitignore` to initialize my repositories. Such a commit should also be universally compatible with any repository/branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is only a partial answer at the moment -- I believe it accurately describes the cause, but it does not offer a solution.]

---

I wrote a script to test this behavior:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

make CFLAGS="-g -O0 -Wall" -j 10 > /dev/null || exit 125
PATH="$PWD:$PATH"

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d repoXXXXXX)
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT

git -C "$tmpdir" init
echo this is a test > "$tmpdir/file1"
git -C "$tmpdir" add file1
git -C "$tmpdir" commit -m test --allow-empty --only
tree=$(git -C "$tmpdir" cat-file -p HEAD^{tree})

if [[ -z "$tree" ]]; then
    echo OKAY
    retval=0
else
    echo FAIL
    retval=1
fi

exit "$retval"
```

We can use this script with [`git bisect`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) to find when this behavior changed:

```
git bisect start HEAD v2.39.2
git bisect run ./test-empty-commit.sh
```

The `git bisect` process shows the the behavior changed in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03267e8656c23cf1e2d1df8204d4cee236fb0077):

```
commit 03267e8656c23cf1e2d1df8204d4cee236fb0077
Author: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason <avarab@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 19:17:39 2022 +0100

    commit: discard partial cache before (re-)reading it
    
    The read_cache() in prepare_to_commit() would end up clobbering the
    pointer we had for a previously populated "the_index.cache_tree" in
    the very common case of "git commit" stressed by e.g. the tests being
    changed here.
    
    We'd populate "the_index.cache_tree" by calling
    "update_main_cache_tree" in prepare_index(), but would not end up with
    a "fully prepared" index. What constitutes an existing index is
    clearly overly fuzzy, here we'll check "active_nr" (aka
    "the_index.cache_nr"), but our "the_index.cache_tree" might have been
    malloc()'d already.
    
    Thus the code added in 11c8a74a64a (commit: write cache-tree data when
    writing index anyway, 2011-12-06) would end up allocating the
    "cache_tree", and would interact here with code added in
    7168624c353 (Do not generate full commit log message if it is not
    going to be used, 2007-11-28). The result was a very common memory
    leak.
    
    Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason <avarab@gmail.com>
    Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau <me@ttaylorr.com>
```

Which introduced the following change in `builtin/commit.c`:

```
diff --git a/builtin/commit.c b/builtin/commit.c
index e22bdf23f5..c291199b70 100644
--- a/builtin/commit.c
+++ b/builtin/commit.c
@@ -987,8 +987,11 @@ static int prepare_to_commit(const char *index_file, const char *prefix,
        struct object_id oid;
        const char *parent = "HEAD";
 
-       if (!active_nr && read_cache() < 0)
-           die(_("Cannot read index"));
+       if (!active_nr) {
+           discard_cache();
+           if (read_cache() < 0)
+               die(_("Cannot read index"));
+       }
 
        if (amend)
            parent = "HEAD^1";
```

---

Update: I've reported this to the git mailing list along with a proposed solution: https://lore.kernel.org/git/bt4342bdip3nzlikjsv6wozszmcbsc2av6cyo3z2lra4jhx3ii@ut2sl5h4f5xn/T/#u

Comment: Thank you very much for the analysis, the reporting and a fix suggestion.

Comment: Has it been accepted as valid bug report with a realistic chance it will be fixed soon?

Comment: The primary git maintainer seems to have acknowledged it as a legitimate bug report. I don't know what that means in terms of time for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

> If the first, how to create an empty commit though files have been staged?

The obvious way is to say `git stash` first. So:

```
git add .
# oops, I've just realized I want to start with an empty commit
git stash
git commit --allow-empty -minitial
git stash pop
# and now `readme.txt` is back in the index
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not touch the working tree.